# is there an equivalent of wp7's marketplacereviewtask for windows 8 / winrt / metro style?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

I've looked through MSDN on both the Store API and the Launchers collection, and can't seem to find a task or launcher that would open up an application in the Marketplace application ready for a user to rate, [as we could really easily do in Windows Phone 7](http://www.nickharris.net/2010/11/marketplacereviewtask/). Is there an alternative way that I can easily point a user towards leaving a review/rating, or are we going to have to wait until MS provides this, or does it already exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe, or should I say "I hope", that the "rate and review" command appears automatically under the settings charm for all applications downloaded from the store.

Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: yeah, you're 100% right - i came across a post on MSDN at some stage but can't find the link again :\

Comment: here we go - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/winappswithcsharp/thread/3cba0db4-c2f6-4c79-98a9-0f740dfacf61

Answer (score 2):

Yes it looks like you are right, in the Guidelines for app settings (Windows Store apps) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh770544.aspx#user_experience , says that in the charm setting under Rate & Review, the user can rate and review your application.

However: "Only apps that are installed through the Windows Store have the Rate and review entry point."