# Launching the Windows Store listing from Win RT / Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

On Windows Phone there's a marketplace review task.

Is there **any** way to implement the equivalent functionality in WinRT apps?

I realize that there's the "rate and review" button in the Charms bar, however, this is not what I need, as I want to integrate a button inside the app to launch the review UI.

It may seem trivial, however, this is one of the most important requirements!

This is not a duplicate of [is there an equivalent of wp7's marketplacereviewtask for windows 8 / winrt / metro style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578342/is-there-an-equivalent-of-wp7s-marketplacereviewtask-for-windows-8-winrt-me) because the questioner was happy with the Charms bar method.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in C# this way:

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-windows-store:REVIEW?PFN=PACKAGENAME"));
```

Where Package Name is to be replaced with yours, which can be found in Package.appxmanifest under the packaging tab.

Comment: I also have a blogpost with more details and how to find your app ID: http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2012/09/11/Linking-to-Your-Windows-Store-App.aspx

Comment: Get the name pakage programly - https://andrearegoli.wordpress.com/2014/01/17/rate-and-review-winrt-app/