# Windows 10 Feedback Task for my App

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-10-universal

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293036/launching-the-windows-store-listing-from-win-rt-windows-8-app) which invokes the Windows 10 store to allow a user to write a review or rate an app, I'd also like to be able to invoke the Windows 10 Feedback app and allow users to provide feedback there.

I cannot seem to find much information on:

1. How this works in general. Can any old app use this service? (I
   notice it just kind of shows whatever apps I have running)
2. How to invoke the Windows Feedback app with my package id

[image: Windows 10 Feedback screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short - not that I can see.

Other apps are invoked via protocol activation. I haven't seen this documented for the feedback app though so I have to err on the side of 'we haven't made this available yet' (I'm still checking though)

Here's an overall guide to the process http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/10/walkthrough-using-windows-8-custom.html?m=1

When I look in the registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol I see (shortened a tad)

> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId\Microsoft.WindowsFeedback...\ActivatableClassId\App.AppX7eaybq6p4x7d4jgd6w6jk7r5dg6yhmbf.mca\CustomProperties]
>
> "Name"="windows-feedback"

So - give that a try via launching windows-feedback

If I do Windows Key-R (run): **windows-feedback://**

it works fine so this should work:

```
var uri = new Uri(@"windows-feedback://");

var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);

if (success)
{
   // URI launched
}
else
{
   // URI launch failed
}
```

**Update**

I've done some searching and it seems the magic parameter there is 
windows-feedback:?contextid=522
That launches the NFL feedback for example. This is a predetermined number - I'm not sure how one gets on this list though.

Comment: Thanks shall play around with that. Would you guess that the package name is passed in a similar way as the store protocol? The store seems to have a vertb "REVIEW" followed by the pfn parameter

Comment: who knows :) would have to see what gets passed to the app. I'm not sure if anything launches the feedback app with parameters.

Comment: The NFL on Windows app has this feature on their about page and it does open to their app. Will experiment :)

Comment: NFL is a Microsoft app (Microsoft.NFLOnWindows...) but the magic I listed above. windows-feedback:?contextid=522  There you have it :)